# Capturar parte da string entre determinados caracteres repetida N vezes

Tags: php, string

Tenho uma string que tem o formato de rotas:

```
/foo/
/{bar}/
/foo/{bar}
/{foo}/{bar}
/{foo}/bar/
```

Pode ter inúmeros valores entre barras, os valores entre `{}` são variáveis

Eu queria capturar todas as ocorrências de `{qualquercoisa}` dessas strings, por exemplo:

```
/foo/{bar}     =>   ["bar"]
/foo/bar       =>   []
/{foo}/{bar}/  =>   ["foo", "bar"]
```

Tentei com `preg_match`, mas só consegui capturar uma ocorrência:

```
preg_match("/\{([^\/]+)\}/", "/foo/{bar}/{baz}/", $match);
//$match = ["{bar}", "bar"]
preg_match("/(?:\{([^\/]+)\}\/?|[^\/]+\/?)+/", "/foo/{bar}/{baz}/", $match);
//$match = ["foo/{bar}/{baz}/", "baz"]
```

Como capturar todas as ocorrências?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para capturar mais de uma ocorrência é necessário utilizar a função `preg_match_all()` os valores casados são inserido no terceiro.

Use uma regex mais simples, case o valor das chaves em um grupo

```
$str = '/{foo}/{bar}';

 preg_match_all('#{([\w]+)}#', $str, $m);

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($m);
```

Saída:

Array

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {foo}
            [1] => {bar}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo
            [1] => bar
        )

)
```

Comment: Que mancada esquecer do `_all`, valeu pela ajuda